# How to access file /data/data from android emulator from Genymotion?

Tags: android, eclipse, genymotion

I love using Genymotion emulator with such brilliant speed to load Android. It has very wonderful speed but still have some instability performance.

How I can access file in **/data/data/** in Genymotion emulator from file explorer in Eclipse? I know that in this device has also installed Superuser permission so I can use this application in root condition. But how I can access this from file explorer?

I know such operation using **adb-shell** and then basic terminal command also. I have successfully with this method but I want access this through file explorer from eclipse so I can easily pull from emulator.

Comment: do you have solution for this !

Comment: Really? What adb command did you use? Because I cant pull from data/data from genymotion device.

Comment: you can use `adb-shell` and then sign in as super user with `su` command

Comment: Oh my god,its simple,just enable su in android virtual device in app called Genimotion configuration!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As of now the only way to access data/data folder on the GenyMotion emulator is by using adb shell commands.
Since the emulator is running inside Oracle VirtualBox, direct access to the storage is a security issue and therefore you wont be able to find it through explorer or eclipse.
The VM saves the storage in .vmdk file format. Which is a virtual machine disk format. The data/data folder is somewhere deep inside that file.

Click [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VMDK)!
To learn more about .vmdk file format.